# How to import csv file in Datagridview with certain columns and rows?

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

I'm new to VB.net and I don't know how to display certain columns and rows in datagridview that was imported from CSV file. My problem is I have many columns and all I want to display is 2 columns:

Name,Age,Mobile Number,ID number

Alex,18,09848484841,0010

George,19,02987654321,0020

Toni,17,09277470257,0030

How can I display only the Name & Age columns and its rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a datatable you get the data structure and collection together.  something like this:

```
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(filename)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
    dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)), _
                         New DataColumn(newline(1))})
    While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
        newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
        Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        newrow.ItemArray = {newline(0), newline(1)}
        dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
    End While
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about man! You got it! Thank you. You're the man.

Comment: Hey @tinstaff, When im using this code, i got the error of "Index was outside the bounds of the array." in the code newrow.ItemArray = {newline(0), newline(1)}

Comment: @Aljie, If the line that readline reads, doesn't have at least 2 fields separated by a comma then the newline array won't have enough indexes. You might need a conditional to check if newline's length is at least 2. Sometimes a file will have empty lines in it. This can also happen if the data isn't strongly validated before it's written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom class with properties that match the data you want to store and make an instance of that class for each row of data use read, then have a `List(Of {custom class})` to hold each object and the DGV's `DataSource` property can view the collection in the grid. The property names in the class will be used as the header.